# Как определить поисковых ботов средствами PHP?

Tags: php

Проверяю по юзер-агенту по этому списку:

```
array('rambler','googlebot','aport','yahoo','msnbot','turtle','mail.ru','omsktele','yetibot','picsearch','sape.bot','sape_context','gigabot','snapbot','alexa.com',
 'megadownload.net','askpeter.info','igde.ru','ask.com','qwartabot','yanga.co.uk',
 'scoutjet','similarpages','oozbot','shrinktheweb.com','aboutusbot','followsite.com','dataparksearch','google-sitemaps','appEngine-google','feedfetcher-google','liveinternet.ru','xml-sitemaps.com','agama','metadatalabs.com','h1.hrn.ru','googlealert.com','seo-rus.com','yaDirectBot','yandeG','yandex','yandexSomething','Copyscape.com','AdsBot-Google','domaintools.com','Nigma.ru','bing.com','dotnetdotcom');
```

Но все одно через проверку проходят боты...
Есть или более совершенный способы проверки?

Comment: Информация содержится  в User-Agent - HTTP..Суди сам , нужен ли другой способ ?

Comment: То есть, вы думаете, что если написать просто массив, все станет работать? Странно, вот бы так всегда =)

Answer (score 0):

Попробовать пакет или писать свой на основе данных из этого пакета https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Одной ссылки для него не хватает.

Answer (score 0):

Для определения поисковых ботов средствами PHP одним из распространённых методов является проверка заголовка User-Agent, который отправляют браузеры и поисковые боты при запросе страницы. Однако, этот метод не является надёжным на 100%, так как User-Agent легко подделать.

Тем не менее, можно попытаться улучшить надёжность проверки, обновив список User-Agent, например, добавив в него более современные боты, такие как Googlebot Smartphones, YandexMobileBot, BingPreview, и т.д.

Вы можете также попробовать использовать реверс-проверку DNS. Этот метод заключается в том, что вы делаете обратный DNS-запрос по IP-адресу, который открыл вашу страницу, и затем делаете прямой DNS-запрос по полученному имени домена. Если прямой DNS-запрос возвращает исходный IP-адрес, то это говорит о том, что IP-адрес принадлежит действительному боту.

Вот пример реверс-проверки DNS для Googlebot:

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if (preg_match('/\.googlebot\.com$/', $hostname)) {
    $ip = gethostbyname($hostname);
    if ($ip == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
        // Это действительно Googlebot
    }
}
```

Однако, стоит учесть, что реверс-проверка DNS может занимать время и замедлить работу вашего сайта, поэтому её следует использовать с осторожностью.

В заключение стоит отметить, что полностью исключить прохождение ботов вряд ли получится, так как они постоянно обновляются и улучшаются. Таким образом, рекомендуется использовать комбинацию различных методов, таких как проверка User-Agent и реверс-проверка DNS, а также регулярно обновлять вашу систему обнаружения ботов, чтобы повысить её эффективность.